# use request when using rest_framework.serializer

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I use Django REST Framework and I have a django model class like this:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I would then want to serialize this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
import models

class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model=models.Venue
        fields=('id','user','is_current_user')
```

where `is_current_user` is a boolean value, somehow like this

```
def is_current_user(self):
    return self.request.user==self.user
```

How can I do this? Do I have request somewhere in serializer? Or should I do this somewhere in the model?

Less convenient options are:

- to send the current user id to the client in another way and compare there, but then I'd have to expose the user of each model to the client.
- to iterate over the json after serialization
- manually without the serializers create a json from a queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=models.Venue
        fields=('id','user','is_current_user')

    def get_is_current_user(self, obj):
        return self.context['request'].user == obj.user
```